# Which way to use for highchart export for vbscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, vbscript, highcharts

I am using classic asp as the script language at server side and highchart for plotting charts. Now for export graphs as PNG which way should I use? The following are a few ways but I can't use them as describe below

1) phantomjs -> for this I will have to call phantomjs.exe by WScript.run. But that is not a suitable way due to browser dependency.

2) java -> For this I will have to install a web server which I can't use.

So please suggest some suitable way to export graphs as image by classis asp.

Comment: You want to save a PNG file of something that you generate client side (in a browser), so I think phantomjs is the only option here. It uses Webkit, so if highchart is compatible with webkit browsers, pahntomjs should work...

Comment: but WScript.run of vbscript do nothing when I run the command to run phantomjs. it also does not give any error. while when I run the command from command line then image created. That's why I think for vbscript phantomjs will not be perfect solution

Comment: Have you tried to install Highcharts [exporting server](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts)? Maybe you have problem with paths while using WScript.run? Simple `echo "Hello World"` works fine for you?

Comment: You can make a batch file and run it from wscript: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/dbabf3db-d9a2-41cf-86c8-89cf6f86ccab/how-to-run-a-batch-file-within-vbscript